# Uncaught Error: jQuery not found running Meteor 1.10.2 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

When I run my Meteor (version 1.10.2) app on firefox. the console prints:

```js
Error: jQuery not found                           dombackend.js:8:8
    module dombackend.js:8
    fileEvaluate modules-runtime.js:346
    require modules-runtime.js:248
    require modules-runtime.js:268
    <anonymous> blaze.js:3735
    <anonymous> blaze.js:3754
TypeError: Package.blaze is undefined             spacebars.js:22:13
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=6f2be25813c793c0b363a6a91ebb029723f294ec:22
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=6f2be25813c793c0b363a6a91ebb029723f294ec:331
```

I read other posts but it was not the same exact error (i.e. some map file) and not the same meteor version.
I am copying some code files over from old app that I want to run under the current meteor version. 
Any suggestions on how to fix these errors?

Thanks

**Edit to answer questions in the comment:**
App originally ran under meteor 1.7.0.1.
App now is expected to run by meteor 1.10.2 installed by chocolatey on windows 10.

Comment: From which version did you upgrade to 1.10.2?

Comment: I did not upgrade, but copied my code files to this new windows 10 laptop after a chocolatey install of meteor.

Comment: Just tried `meteor npm install jquery --save` did not fix it.

Comment: Did you maybe just copied files but missed to copy Meteor packages that are required?

Answer (score 0):

run this cmd `meteor add jquery` will be work

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

> I am copying some code files over from old app

From my understanding, you are trying to upgrade meteor from 1.7.0.1 to 1.10.2

If this the case, I would argue coping source code is the right approach to the job. you miss all the package dependencies in the old setup.

I would suggest you keep the source code in the old package, just bumping up the meteor version, update dependent packages, try to run the app, then fix the broken changes if necessary.